# Why would my app suddenly start wanting a .resources file?

Tags: .net, fuslogvw

I made a change in my forms based C# app where I changed some dialogs to no longer handle multiple locales for the resources (gave up on translating all the text). Since doing that, the app now does not load because it says (FUSLOGVW):

```
The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = AutoTagCore.resources, Version=16.1.73.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=200c326bc129ca1f
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files/Windward Studios/Windward Report Designer/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = NULL
Calling assembly : AutoTagCore, Version=16.1.73.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=200c326bc129ca1f.
```

What/why would it be building and then requiring a .resources file?

thanks - dave

Comment: Look at the exception's stack trace.  But somewhat predictable that you see that ResourceManager can no longer find the satellite assembly and can't find it embedded in the assembly so now goes hunting for the .resources file.

Comment: @HansPassant - What should I look for to see why it's not embedding the resources in the DLL? thanks - dave

Comment: I assume you have source control system, right? Compare the two revisions in it to see what you have modified. Then enable MSBuild diagnostics logging in both cases. The diff around `AutoTagCore` can easily show you what might be wrong. `en-US` is usually the default locale set in an application, and then there is no need to load such a resource file, but the code base you work on might have its own settings (rare, but possible) which might require an explicit copy of this file.

Comment: @LexLi - I know it's removing those locale specific resource files. The question is why did that then want the .resource file. And more importantly, how do I undo it wanting that? thanks - dave

Comment: Like I said, you, as the sole person in this thread who can access the code, should do your own digging, because nobody else can see the code. I already provided hints on what might help. MCVE is required if you are eager to see an answer, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/